# How to open JQuery Datatable Render column which is URL in new window using return

Tags: jquery, url, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatable1.10.12. using AJAX & JSON. I have column names which are URLs . When I click the column names I can't open the URLs in a new window in  web browsers. It's opening in the same window. Any Advise would be great on How to get it done.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        //  asmx service to retrive the  data from server side
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("FirmDetailService.asmx/GetFirmDetails")%>',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
       $('#example').DataTable({
           searchHighlight: true,
           lengthChange: false,
           language: {
               searchPlaceholder: "Search records"},
                data: data,
                'columns': [
                             { 'data':'PID', 'visible':false},
                             { 'data' : 'PersonName',
                               'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                   var idp = row['PID'];                                   
       return '<a href="FirmsDeatils.aspx?id=' + idp + '">' + data + '</a>';
                             }                        
                             },
                             { 'data': 'CID', 'visible':false },
                             { 'data': 'CompanyName',
                               'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                 var idc = row['CID'];
       return '<a href="FirmsDeatils.aspx?id=' + idc + '">' + data + '</a>';
                             }
                             },
                             { 'data': 'City' },
                             { 'data': 'Country' },
                         ]
                            }
            ); 
        }
    });
   }
   );
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `target="_blank"` attribute for `<a>` elements.

For example:

```
return '<a target="_blank" href="FirmsDeatils.aspx?id=' + idp + '">' + data + '</a>';
```